# How do I use openHome to implement DLNA UPNP control point under xCode 4.6?

Tags: xcode4.6, upnp, dlna

I am trying to implement a DLNA UPNP control point under xCode 4.6.1 for iPad. I have found a [project](http://www.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) that makes open source code that makes exactly this, but I can't find those exact functions either in the source code or in the documentation.

Do I need to create a static library out of that and include it in the iOS source (in this case, how do I use that?)?

Comment: Can you add much more info to your question please?  What app do you want to write (e.g. a control point for standard UPnP media renderers or OpenHome renderers)?  Which platform(s) does your app target?  Where have you looked for code or docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ohNet page](http://wiki.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) should be pretty self-explanatory.

It is a UPnP stack.  It'll handle all communication between control point and media server / media renderer.  It won't automatically control a media renderer; you have to write the code to do this.

Overview and API docs for ohNet are linked from the above page.  Docs for a UPnP media renderer are available from the [UPnP forum](http://upnp.org/resources/upnpresources.zip) (see the standardizeddcps/MediaServer_1 and MediaRenderer_1 directory inside the zip).  Docs for [ohMedia services](http://www.openhome.org/wiki/OhMediaDevelopers) are available from the OpenHome site.

You mentioned wanting to write a "DLNA UPnP control point".  DLNA vs UPnP is a regular source of confusion.  UPnP describes the protocols and APIs you need to control a UPnP media renderer.  DLNA is an optional layer on top of this which gives you greater confidence of interoperability and the rights to use the DLNA name/logo in marketing materials.  You do not need DLNA compliance; if you choose to implement it, you'll have to join DLNA and pay (a relatively large amount) for access to the specs.